# Sails.js: load script on a specific view

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In Sails.js how can I load a javascript file in a specific view, because I have an script that I want to load only in one view (.ejs).

I see that in layout.ejs all the javascript files are loaded for all views, so the idea is to exclude the javascript file from the layout and load inside the view.

```
  <!--SCRIPTS-->
  <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/textAngular-rangy.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/textAngular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/textAngular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-color-picker.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-click-outside.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/angular-filemanager.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/dependencies/resource.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/locales/ca.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/locales/en.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/locales/es.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/IndexController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/LogoutController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/NewVideoController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/PreviewController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/VideoConfigController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers/layoutController.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/LoginService.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/VideoConfigService.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/VideoService.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/authInterceptor.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/services/authToken.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/test/controllers/IndexController-spec.js"></script>
  <!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

The code above are the scripts of the layout. I would like to remove the textAngular scripts from the layout and load only in the view that uses textAngular.

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer.. but can't you remove the textAngular scripts from layout.ejs, and only add them as <script/> tags in the .ejs files that need them?

Comment: This script links are generated automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're loading different scripts on different pages as part of the actual behavior of your application, I'd advise against it.  (But it looks like you're using Angular, so that's probably not the case, since you're probably attaching UI controllers to a particular page via `ng-controller`).

So, on the other hand, assuming you're looking into doing this for performance reasons, then here's what I'd suggest:

First lift with `--prod` and check to see what each page load feels like.  Now that you're using a minified bundle, it should be considerably faster.  Pay particular attention to what subsequent page loads feel like, since your browser will have cached everything by then.  Because of the way the browser (and HTTP v1) work, in most cases you'll find that using a single bundle in production is actually faster then including only those scripts used on a particular page.  (Plus it makes switching to a CDN much easier if that ever comes up).

That said, if you're using *tons* of JavaScript files (megabytes and megabytes), that might not always be an option.  What we usually do at my company in that scenario is what @KevinLe suggested: manually include the really heavy scripts on the page that needs them.  (Even then, you can probably still use the linker for everything else-- or vice versa).

Alternatively, you could get fancy with Grunt or Gulp-- just keep in mind that, when you go to production and you consider using a CDN, you'll have to bundle up those scripts for each individual view into separate payloads.

---

#### So to recap:

- avoid writing front-end code that does stuff immediately when it is loaded without first checking the DOM
- for most apps, you should just use a single bundle (performance will be better)
- if you need to separate things out, include scripts manually in the views where you need them  (note that if you do this and also decide to continue using the linker, then you'll probably want to move the linker tags out of layout.ejs and into each individual view as well-- that keeps your script tags in one place in the code)